# Define of Series Sum Using Python

Tags: python, sum

```
def Series_Sum(arg1, arg2, function):
    for arg1 in range(arg2):
        result =+ function(arg1) 
        return result

Series_Sum(0,10, arg1)
```

I am trying to define series summation like mathematical symbol "Sigma" while its function is as much as detached and could be called later on from the different defining.

above is what I had made but it returns error :

"arg1" is not defined.

any solutions?

Add :

```
def Series_Sum(arg1, arg2):
    for arg1 in range(arg2+1):
        result =+ arg1       
    return result

print(Series_Sum(0,10))
```

Why it does not return 55?

Comment: Yes. The solution would be  to pass something that is actually defined... (hint: it's not `arg1`)

Comment: Also, you're returning inside your loop, defeating the very purpose of the loop. Any thoughts on why that is?

Comment: Are you sure about the indentation ? Remember, in python it matters. Also, `result =+ 3` probably doesn't do what you want. It affects the value `+3` to `result`.

Comment: its `+=` not  `=+`

Answer (score 0):

in your last line of the code, you try to pass arg1 as a parameter, but there is no such object defined in that scope.
You also have a couple of bugs in your function. This implementation might help

```
def Series_Sum(arg1, arg2, function):
    result = 0
    for x in range(arg1,arg2+1):
        result += function(x) 
    return result

Series_Sum(0,10, <function goes here>)
```

Example :

```
# myFunction returns square of the input number
def myFunction(num) :
    return num**2

def Series_Sum(lower, upper, function) :
    result = 0
    for x in range(lower,upper+1) :
        result += function(x)
    return result

# print sum of series : 6^2 + 7^2 + 8^2 + ... + 20^2
print(Series_Sum(6,20,myFunction))
```

Result -> `2415`

Comment: why does the result =0 must be happened before the for statment start?

Comment: result variable needs to be defined before it is used... You might be putting the result=0 line inside for loop, it must be placed in the function before for loop

Comment: Don't use `_` as your name for each element in that range unless you **don't plan to use it**. `function(_)` is poor form. If you're iterating over a range and using the numbers in that range, why not use variable names that actually make sense, like: `for n in range(arg1, arg2+1)`...

Comment: @blacksite Edited.